# Combine two lists into hierarchical tree

Tags: php, mysql

I've two tables that I've to combine to one hierarchical tree.

**Table 1: Code structure**

```
+--------+-------------+
|  Code  | Description |
+--------+-------------+
| A      | Descr 1     |
| A1     | Descr 2     |
| A101   | Descr 3     |
| B      | Descr 4     |
| B2     | Descr 5     |
| B202   | Descr 6     |
| B20201 | Descr 7     |
+--------+-------------+
```

**Table 2: Costs**

```
+--------+-------------+------------+
|  Code  | Description | Cost total |
+--------+-------------+------------+
| A101   | Cost 1     |      10000  |
| B20201 | Cost 2     |      20000  |
+--------+-------------+------------+
```

The challenge for me is to get the folowing output:

```
A Descr 1
--A1 Descr 2
----A101 Descr 3
------A101 Cost 1 10000
B - Descr 4
--B2 Descr 5
----B202 Descr 6
------B20201 Descr 7
--------B20201 Cost 1 20000
```

How can I create such a hierarchial list? Can someone point me in the right direction?

The main problem for me is to create a multidimensional array from the list of codes (A, A1, A101, etc.).

Comment: You can't use only SQL to work with this. Mysql doesn't provide native element to run recursive statement. You'll have to build sql request using PHP.
Maybe you should consider using another sgbd like postgresql which embed recursive loop for sql queries.

Comment: Ok, clear. Unfortunatly I can't change the database engine. So I've to use php for this. How can I create a multidimensional array of a list like (A, A1, A101, etc.)?

Comment: it depend on your rules to define A101. What does this means ? is this rules scalable to any level of sub-hierarchies or is it a static number of sub-hierarchies ?

Comment: You're using the "enumerated path" model of representing hierarchical data, which can solve this problem by sorting the resultset by `Code` and then searching backwards to find the most recent record whose `Code` is a substring of the current one—but you'd probably find it easier to restructure your database to use the "nested sets" or "transitive closure table" models instead. [@Bill Karwin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/20860) introduces them nicely in his presentation [Models for Hierarchical Data with SQL and PHP](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data).

Comment: Is there a max number of levels?  1st character 1 level, 2nd character 2nd Level...3 & 4 3rd level position 5,6 4th level... is that as far as it goes?

Comment: Yes, there's a max number of levels (in this case there are 6 levels). I think I've to create an adjecency list to keep it simple, right?

Comment: if i understaind your logic `A101 Descr 3` and `A101 Cost 1 10000` should be in the same level, no ?

Comment: Yes, that's true, but the A101 Descr 3 is the group name, where A101 Cost 1 10000 belongs to.